# Font-size overrides other styles

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to use the `font-size:0;` hack for getting rid of white space on my grid system.

I've set the body font size to 0, then am specifying the sizes for my text elsewhere.

However the font-size:0; seems to override and my text cannot be seen?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkfoyyzy/)

```
div{font-size:0;}
h1{font-size:1.5em;}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in which situation you need to use `font-size:0`? Note that this technique has some problems on Android

Comment: The example (and the jsfiddle) does not set body font size at all. And there is no override. Your `1.5em` just evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 1):

A `em` value is defined relative to the size of the font on the parent element. Therefore the calculated value of `1.5em;` would be `0` in this case.

You could either [use a root-em `rem`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wkfoyyzy/1/) or a [fixed length value as `px`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wkfoyyzy/3/).

> **[15.7 Font size: the 'font-size' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-size)**
>
> 'em' and 'ex' length values refer to the computed font size of the
>   current element. On the 'font-size' property, these length units refer
>   to the computed font size of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised, it is because `ems` are a relative number, relative to their parents. So this will only work if you specify px values for your text.

Answer (score 0):

A `em` value is relative to the size of the font on the parent element. Since your `div` elements `font-size:0` the `h1` element takes the relative value of `0`. In this case you have to use either some specific values to your `attributes`. For Instance

```
font-size: 10px;
```